# Error when Creating a Template for a Matrix

Tags: c++

I was able to define a template for printing vectors to screen. It works as expected. Here it is.

```
template<typename T>
void PrintVector( std::vector<T> vec ){
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator iIt = vec.begin();
    for ( ; iIt != vec.end(); ++iIt ){
        std::cout << *iIt << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now what I'd like to do is create a similar template except for matrices (vector of vectors). I thought I would try something like this.

```
template<typename T>
void PrintMatrix( std::vector<std::vector<T>> mat ){
    int i,j;
    for ( i(0); i<mat.size(); ++i ){
        for ( j(0); j<mat.at(i).size(); ++j){
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However when I try to use `PrintMatrix(MyMatrix)` in my code I get the following error:

`error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`

It's not clear to me how to interpret this error. Could someone provide a hint as to why the `PrintVector` template worked but not `PrintMatrix`? What am I missing?

I appreciate it.

Comment: How are you calling the function-templates? What line of code gives you the error?

Comment: You really should be passing those vectors by `const reference` not by value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you for the tip, I will do that. Could you please provide a reason why though?

Comment: Passing by value incurs an unnecessary copying of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable initialization `i(0)` and `j(0)` are possible only in declare-initialize expressions. You can fix it by moving variable types to the assignments. That expressions without declarations look like function calls, and you get the errors "terms i and j do not evaluate to functions taking 1 arguments", since they are int variables.

```
template<typename T>
void PrintMatrix( std::vector<std::vector<T>> mat ){
    for (int i(0); i<mat.size(); ++i ){
        for (int j(0); j<mat.at(i).size(); ++j){
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Why have you used such initialization instead of intuitively clear assignments `i = 0` and `j = 0`?

Comment: Thank you! As to why I did it? It wasn't intentional, I just didn't know any better. But now I do. Thank you for the advice as well as what was needed to resolve the issue.